# Trying to smooth small 'bumps' in graph data using spline interpolation for changepoint detection

Tags: r, splines, anomaly-detection, change-point, gradient

I'm trying to detect changes in my data, I want to identify points that are like local minima and shoot upwards. I have used the changepoint package to do so, and upon running it and selecting my penalties I get this 
[image]

There are too many red marks on the circled parts, and I can't have these because I am only interested in the point of local minima shooting upwards, ie- the very first red mark in these series of red points. I have tried using ggplot to identify local minima but it returns these red marks too. I have tried using spline interpolation, but it simply returns more red marks than before. Any help would be great.
Thank you

Comment: One technique to try is a simple sliding window filter, which slides along the data taking the mean of the data points in the window, moving along one data point at a time. You could try different window widths to effect different smoothing.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thanks for the reply! wouldn't that change the position of the local minima we're looking for though?

Comment: Not if you choose a small enough window

Comment: Easy to make a simple test for verification.

Comment: Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are seeing here is that you are using a method to estimate a change in mean when you are, in fact, wanting to identify a change in trend.  This is why you have several changepoints identified in the circled region.

You may wish to consider using the EnvCpt package which contains code to identify changes in trend using PELT - although these will be available in the next release of the changepoint package, v.2.3, a beta copy is available on [github](https://github.com/rkillick/changepoint).

Comment: Hey! Sorry I'm a newbie here, would doing envcpt::cpt.reg be the same as downloading the beta version and going cpt.reg ?

Comment: Yes.  This is a direct port of functionality.